# Trying to Embed answer from SQL Query(PHP Variable) in XML doc

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

Hi So this is my first time posting something here, been working on this for a few days but no luck. Basically I am querying a database in php, getting my answer but I want to send this answer to an XML file for graph creation.
Any help would be greatfully appreciated.

Here is the part of the PHP file with embedded sql that returns variable.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
"SELECT COUNT(*) as FullCount 
FROM DailyShpm 
WHERE (curr_date between '2013-01-01' and now()- INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
AND (Product= 'AE')
");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['FullCount'] ;
echo "<- Full results for total AE to date for 2013";
echo "<br>";
echo $row['FullCount'] ;
echo "<br>";


$files ="data.xml";

//load xml object
$xml= simplexml_load_file($files);

//assign value

$xml->set->value = $row['FullCount'];
//$xml->chart ->set = $row['FullCount'];


//store the value into the file
file_put_contents($file, $xml->asXML());
}
```

Here is what it outputs in the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<chart caption="Year to Date" xAxisName="Year" yAxisName="Amount of Shipments Air Exports"> 



<set label="2013" value=""><value>7707</value></set> 
<set label="2014" value=""/>
```

I need the value of 7707 to be put in the value within set label="2013" value"7707"

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following:

```
$xml->set->value = $row['FullCount'];
```

to:

```
$xml->attributes()->value = ((string) $xml->attributes()->value) . $row['FullCount'];
```

Comment: Hi m1kfb thanks for your comment but after I run the php file, the xml file is still empty....Any ideas?

Comment: @user3898780: That's contradicting: In your question the XML file is *not* empty. Here you say it's still empty.

Comment: file_put_contents($file, $xml->asXML()); should be file_put_contents($files, $xml->asXML()); it's missing the 's'.

Comment: So this was solved by $xml->set->attributes()->value = ((string) $xml->attributes()->value) . $row['FullCount']; Now I have the issue where the value of 2013 is getting overwritten by the 2014 value. Is there any way to set the attribute value where label = 2013 and 2014?// Thanks in advance

Comment: if($xml->attributes()->label == '2013') { ((string) $xml->attributes()->value) . $row['FullCount']; } and same for 2014. Is that what you mean?